# how to calculated elapse time between 2 orders

Tags: ms-access

I have the following table :

```
     tCustomerOrder
     -IdOrder
     -IdCustomer
     -OrderDate
```

I want a query to get a table with :

```
     -Idcustomer
     -LastOrder_date
     -LastOrder_Id
     -LastOrder_period   ''ie elasped time between the two last orders
     -NextOrder_Date     ''estimated date egal to LastOrder_date + LastOrder_period
```

I success to have LastOrder_Date (using MaxDom function to calculate a new fied) but when I use DiffDate it return en error.

```
     LastOrder_Date: MaxDom("OrderDate";""tCustomerOrder"";"[IdCustomer]=" [IdCustomer] & " AND [IdOrder]<>" & [IdOrder] & " AND  [OrderDate] < " & [OrderDate])

     DiffDate("\d";[tCustomerOrder];[LastOrderDate])
```

Must I have to use aggregate query? How do it work?
Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Is your LastOrder_Date returning something ? Sometimes `Null`, perhaps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks to 
[MS Access SQL: Aggregating on Min Value but retrieving other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063408/ms-access-sql-aggregating-on-min-value-but-retrieving-other-fields?rq=1)

Here is the solution :

```
SELECT a.IdClient, a.LivraisonDateMax, m.IdCommande, 
m.NextLivraisonDelay, m.NextLivraisonDate
FROM 
(
   (
    SELECT IdClient, 
    Max(LivraisonDate) AS LivraisonDateMax 
    FROM qryBILANCommandeClient_All GROUP BY IdClient)  
    AS a INNER JOIN qryBILANCommandeClient_All AS m 
    ON (a.LivraisonDateMax = m.LivraisonDate) AND (a.IdClient = m.IdClient
    )
) 
INNER JOIN tClient_General ON a.IdClient = tClient_General.IdClient
ORDER BY tClient_General.DesignationCourte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateDiff` function instead of `DiffDate`

Comment: OP seems to use a French MS-Access

Comment: Of course I use a French MS-Access. I correct the expression as follow  DiffDate("j";[LastOrder_Date];[OrderDate]) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate LastOrder_Date, but then you try to use [LastOrderDate]
(missing `_` in name)